# Echo the results to show all values with for each

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a working MySql select with an inner join:

```
      $estateSettings = getEstateOptionsArray();
        foreach($estateSettings as $s) {
            $i  = url_title($s, "", true);
            $data = $wpdb->get_col("
                SELECT meta.meta_value 
                FROM $wpdb->postmeta meta
                INNER JOIN wp_posts ON meta.post_id = wp_posts.id
                WHERE meta.meta_key = '{$i}' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate'
            ");
            $returnData = $s." : ";
            foreach($data as $v) { 
                $returnData .= $v.", ";


        }



        }
```

It's ok, $v contains the values, but the problem is if I simply `echo` it out it only shows the last result value. If I `echo` it like this:

```
echo $returnData .= $v.", ";
```

it shows the names and all result values.

How can I `echo` the results without the returnData and to show all values?

I'm stuck again. I managed to get only the values, but it repeats them

```
 $ingatlanSettings = getIngatlanOptionsArray();
            foreach($ingatlanSettings as $s) {
                $i  = url_title($s, "", true);
                $data = $wpdb->get_col("
                    SELECT meta.meta_value 
                    FROM $wpdb->postmeta meta
                    INNER JOIN wp_posts ON meta.post_id = wp_posts.id
                    WHERE meta.meta_key = '{$i}' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ingatlan'
                ");
                $returnData = $s." : ";
                foreach($data as $v) { 
                    $returnData .= $v.", ";
                    $result[] = $v; 

            }

            $res = $element.implode($result);
            echo $res;

            }
```

Comment: what does '$wpdb->get_col' do?

Comment: @Tokk: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#SELECT_a_Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo $returnData.implode(',', $data);
```

use this instead of loop.

Comment: Isn't that the same as just saying `echo $returnData . implode(',', $data);`. The loop becomes unnecessary at that point.

Comment: @Michael McTiernan : Thanks. I didn't notice that.

Comment: dont missunderstand me but i love ya, i was able to make it with your help, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
$returnData .= $s." : ";
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { 
                    $returnData .= $value.", ";
}
```

Comment: i mean im still getting the last value

Answer (score 0):

A great way to see what an array contains is this simple script:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($YourArray); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Knowhing what is actually in your array can help solve a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

> its ok and all, $v contains the
>   values, but the problem is if is
>   simply echo it out it only shows the
>   last result value, if i echo it like
>   this echo $returnData .= $v.", "; it
>   shows the names and all result values.

Here's where you're losing me. When you echo out the result, are you doing this:

```
echo $returnData .= $v.", ";
```

Or are you echo'ing:

```
echo $returnData;
```

Doing the latter would return the full string that you've prepared with all values.

I'm trying to understand the nature of your question, though. Are you trying to format `$returnData` in a specific way, but then return the raw data?

Answer (score 0):

thank you everybody for the help, i was able to do ot

```
$returnData = $s." : ";
                $resdata = array_unique($data);
                foreach($resdata as $v) { 
                    $returnData .= $v.", ";
                    echo $result[] = $v;
```

really big thanks to everybody